# Using image src from asset variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vue-cli

I have a problem with images recently. Everything is ok until you have to show a list of images on the page.

The problem is that when we directly give an `src` for image with hardcoded string, it works with a url like `~/assets/any-image.png`. But if I try to move url into any variable / object / array, I have to specify the `:src="myVariable"` which contains the URL.

The code for example:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    Problem with images
    <img :src="image.url" alt="">
    <img :src='require(image.url)' alt="">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      image:
        {
          url: '~/assets/icon.png',
          type: 'asset'
        }
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Here I tried using assets with `~` and `@`, also with and without slash. Of course the image exists in assets folder, but since the `src` url is provided via any variable (not directly), the assets url is not served and as a result the image url looks like `host:port/~/assets/...` which doesn't exist on the server.

In this example I've got an idea to replace image url with an object containing the url and its type (asset/static) and make checks if type asset, then use `require(variable)` but got the problem that `"Cannot find module '~/assets/icon.png'"`

Has anybody solved this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `require` when binding to an asset variable image.  For example:

```html
<img :src="url">
```

```js
url: require('@/assets/icon.png')
```

If your json contains only the filename, you can place `require` in the template:

```html
<img :src="require('@/assets/' + url)">
```

```js
url: 'icon.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2185093/dan) with his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65128982/11928561)
I've got a final solution which is universal:
Image contain it's link and type:

```js
image: {
  url: '/any-asset-folder/image.png'
  type: 'asset'
}
```

Then with ternary operator result is

```js
<img
  :src="image.type === 'asset' 
    ? require('@/assets'+image.url) 
    : image.url"
>
```

In this way I've got images working both if they are from assets or static or external :)